# How to convert a string like "1+23-56" into a number

Tags: java, string, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/java-evaluate-string-to-math-expression)

How can I convert a string representing a math expression, like "1+23-56," into a number? I am trying to do this in Java.

Comment: It would help if you gave what language you were trying to do this in.

Comment: what technology are you using? Regular expressions are very useful in situations like these. They allow you to match the pattern and extract what you need.

Comment: since you don't specify language, I'll assume you're using javascript.  just pass it into eval()

Comment: Language Language Language bro ...????

Comment: Try to search for an expression parser.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create your own language specification, with your own grammar and then implement it, there are several examples of how to write a language for a calculator.

The basic principle is to first do a syntax analisis, generate a syntactic tree and the parse it using your language rules, the semantic analisis.

Here are some examples:

- http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn4
- http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn24

Comment: I am trying to do this in Java.